# LocalDB does not starts correctly for IIS worker process

Tags: iis, sql-server-2012-localdb

When I deployed MVC application on IIS then localDB databse is not starting correctly. Error message is as follows:
Windows API call WaitForMultipleObjects returned error code: 575. Windows system error message is: {Application Error}
The application was unable to start correctly (0x%lx). Click OK to close the application.
Reported at line: 3621.

But the localDB is working fine with visual studio application and with sqlserver management studio. I already have restarted it and recreated it by command prompt to make it work. But nothing is working. The problem came when i re installed IIS in my machine. 
How can i fix this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the user which runs the application pool instance has access to the localDB. One way to test it is to add your own credentials

Comment: Did you register asp.net components on IIS  (Aspnet_regiis.exe)? Is plain asp.net page aspx working correctly?

Comment: It sounds like the issue is either a settings issues, or an authentication issue. I dont think it has to do with access to the database yet, because you would of received a different error code.

Were you able to ping your IIS server successfully, and check the service settings in the web.config for your application?

Comment: User is administrator and has been able to run LocalDB just fine in the past. This is an issue that popped up seemingly out of the blue. At least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete all files in `"C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0"` folder. Give write permissions to `v11.0` folder. If you can't create another instance give write permission to `Instances` folder.